# If $\lim_{x \to R} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = c \in \mathbb{R}$, does $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n R^n$ converge?

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $R \in \mathbb{R}$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n.$

If $\lim_{x \to R} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ diverges, then $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n R^n$ diverges by Abel's theorem.

My question is here:

If $\lim_{x \to R} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = c \in \mathbb{R}$, does $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n R^n$ converge?

Comment: Are you sure you intend a two-sided limit?

Comment: The geometric series $\sum_n x^n$ should show you that the answer is no.

Comment: @Crostul Thank you very much.

Comment: @EricTowers I intended $\lim_{x \to R-}$.

Comment: This is the Converse of Abel's theorem. An unconditional Converse of Abel's theorem is not true. But there are partial Converses with Additional Hypothesis. For instance if we assume $a_n \ge0\ \forall n$, then it holds. If we assume that $na_n \rightarrow0$, or even that it's Cesaro sum goes to 0, then it holds. There are many other Partial Converses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Consider $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n x^n$ with $R=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much, RRL.